# Algebra equation with integer solutions

Tags: factoring

*If the solution for $(7-k)(8-k)x^2 - (112-15k)x + 56 = 0$ are all integer solutions, what could the value for $k$ be? (There are 4 values)*

My first thought was to put in the quadraic formula and see what the solution will look like.

So put in:
$$x = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$$
Where we'll get
$$x = \frac{112-15k\pm \sqrt{337k^2-5020k+18816}}{2(7-k)(8-k)}$$
after simplification.

However, I found that $337k^2-5020k+18816$ cannot be factorized. What should I do?

Comment: Should $k$ be an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't solve the quadratic equation in $x$ correctly. I obtained
$$
x=\frac{7}{7-k},\quad x=\frac{8}{8-k}.
$$
Indeed, $b^2-4ac=k^2$.

Comment: Futhermore, how can I continue from your solution? This problem has four solutions for k.

Comment: Sorry, forgot that $x$ is an integer also.

Comment: Yes, the two values for $x$ are the solutions of the quadratic equation, which are assumed to be integers. This is the text ("are all integer solutions").